# NSCalendar CurrentCalendar issues

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

My app does a lot of calendar calculations, and so I need to setup a NSCalendar for most of those functions. Now calling `[ NSCalendar currentCalendar ]` seems to be extremely slow, as others have also commented so I thought I could simply cache a copy of NSCalendar. However this NSCalendar from time to time seems to produce garbage which I do not get if I create a new NSCalendar when I need one. I assume that it is either getting deallocated or getting corrupted somehow, which is surprising as I am using "Automatic Reference Counting"

Any suggestions.

PS Could this be due to the fact that NSCalendar is not thread safe?

PSS

I ended up set my CurrentCalendar from the main Thread. This seems to have solved the issue. If anybody has any comments about this please let me know.

R

Comment: Please provide examples of it "producing garbage"

Comment: Its garbage is just wrong data, so it is very difficult to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

As an investigative step, I would recommend that you log the class of the object to see if it is somehow getting changed to another object. For example, if you have this code:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```

Then later on (especially if you can tell when the data gets corrupted), you would then do this:

```
NSLog(@"Calendar class: %@", [cal class]);
```

When all is well, you should get back an __NSCFCalendar.